# Compare two 2D array to match the string

Tags: arrays, perl

I want to compare string in two 2D array but the size are not the same. So, I want to shift the element in one of the array to match with all of the element in another array but i run out of idea on how the looping should be.

This is my first time using perl language. I learned c language before.

```
#!/usr/intel/pkgs/perl/5.14.1/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

@clk = (
'prescc_ux_aux_clk',
'prescc_ux_prim_clk',
'usb2_phy_side_clk',
'usb3_phy_side_clk',
'ux_prim_clk',
'ux_side_clk',
'ux_xtal_frm_refclk',
'uxd_aux_clk',
'uxd_pgcb_clk',
'uxd_prescc_aux_clk',
'uxd_prim_clk',
'uxd_side_clk',
'uxd_suspend_clk');

@clkack = (
'ccu_ux_xtal_frm_refclk_ack',
'ibbs_ux_prim_clkack',
'sbr_ux_side_clkack',
'uxd_aux_clkack',
'uxd_pgcb_clkack',
'uxd_prim_clkack',
'uxd_side_clkack');



foreach(@clk){
    @clkline = map {[split /_/,$_]} @clk;
    }
foreach(@clkack){
    @clkackline = map{[split /_/,$_]} @clkack;
    }

#print Dumper @clkline;

$match = 0;

$clkack_row = @clkackline; #no. of row in clkackline
$clk_row = @clkline;

for ($i=0; $i<$clkack_row; $i++){
    $clkackcolumn = @{$clkackline[$i]};

    for ($j=0; $j<$clkackcolumn; $j++){

        for ($m=0; $m<$clk_row; $m++){
            $clkcolumn = @{$clkline[$m]};

            for ($n=0; $n<$clkcolumn; $n++){
                if ($clkline[$i][$j] eq $clkacline[$m][$n]){
                    $match = $match + 1;
                    print "$match\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect it to loop the @clkackline array and compare it with the @clkline array. If it's matching then it will give how many match it have, hence the $match variable.

Edited:

I need to split it by '_' so that i can get the element divided by only the word inside another array. 
Eg:

```
$clk[0] = ux_prim_clk will result in;
$clkline[0][0] = ux,  $clkline[0][1] = prim, $clkline[0][2] = clk.
```

Then i need to compare with the @clkackline array element by element but in sequential order. 
Eg:

```
$clkline[0][0] = $clkackline[0][0], 
$clkline[0][1] = $clkackline[0][1], 
$clkline[0][2] = $clkackline[0][2].
```

But another problem is i need to compare @clkline with all of the element in clkackline. But since the size will be the constraint, then i need to shift the @clkackline to match with @clkline or vice versa.

Eg:
First check:

```
$clkline[1][0] = $clkackline[0][0], 
$clkline[1][1] = $clkackline[0][1], 
$clkline[1][2] = $clkackline[0][2].
```

Second check:

```
$clkline[1][0] = $clkackline[0][1], 
$clkline[1][1] = $clkackline[0][2], 
$clkline[1][2] = $clkackline[0][3].
```

This is just an example of course, but you can see that i need it to delete the first column in $clkackline[0].

Then i need to calculate the percentage of how much it will match.

Eg:

```
ux_prim_clk vs  uxd_prim_clkack will return 33.33%.
```

Then store the element with highest match inside another array (eg: @clknew)

Comment: Can you share the excepted output.? I am not able to understand. From which array you have to compare. Why you are splting with `_` and assigning to an array. are you searching for [push](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html).

Comment: You should always use `use strict` and `use warnings` in all your Perl programs, and declare your variables with `my`. Your variable names are very hard to read, and `strict` will tell you when you have typos.

Comment: Why not just use a hash?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be over complicating your problem, to answer your original question of comparing two lists I have a script that will compare two lists and tell you what doesn't exist in each. If this inst exactly what you need let me know and we can change it up to fit your use. As with just about anything in Perl there is probably a module that will do all this for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(any);

my @list1 = ('prescc_ux_aux_clk',
'prescc_ux_prim_clk',
'usb2_phy_side_clk',
'usb3_phy_side_clk',
'ux_prim_clk',
'ux_side_clk',
'ux_xtal_frm_refclk',
'uxd_aux_clk',
'uxd_pgcb_clk',
'uxd_prescc_aux_clk',
'uxd_prim_clk',
'uxd_side_clk',
'uxd_suspend_clk'
);

my @list2 = ('ccu_ux_xtal_frm_refclk_ack',
'ibbs_ux_prim_clkack',
'sbr_ux_side_clkack',
'uxd_aux_clkack',
'uxd_pgcb_clkack',
'uxd_prim_clkack',
'uxd_side_clkack'
);

print "\n==== LIST 1 TO LIST 2 COMPARISON, Does not exist in list 2 ====\n";
foreach my $first (@list1) { 
    if ( any { $_ eq $first} @list2) { next; }
        else { print $first . "\n"; }
}

print "\n==== LIST 2 TO LIST 1 COMPARISON, Does not exist in list 1 ====\n";
foreach my $first (@list2) { 
    if ( any {$_ eq $first} @list1) { next; }
        else { print $first . "\n"; }
}
```